# Ask for drive to create dynamic path within a command of a batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, mklink

The title is a bit odd, but I want to create a hard link to a folder where the user specifies the drives.

The command is `mklink /j` and I need `%driveone%`:\Fixed\Path and `%drivetwo%`:\Fixed\Path as it's variables. Anyone know how I can prompt the input to define the drives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set /p "driveone=Drive one ? "
```

is the standard "get user input to a variable" formula.

If you want to input from the command line, then

```
set "driveone=%1"
set "drivetwo=%2"
```

would allow you to run

*yourbatch* c d

to assigng `c` and `d` to driveone/two respectively.